# SQL Server : how to update with string replace

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, replace

How can I update some of columns:

```
UPDATE Product
SET Title = REPLACE(Title , 'mn%', 'za%')
WHERE (Title LIKE N'mn%')
```

Consider data of one column is `mnfmnd` and must be changed to `zafmnd`

Comment: is it always the first two characters?

Comment: @scsimon yes, it's always first characters

Comment: Your query is trying to replace all instances of the string literal mn% in Title. I don't think that is what you want. This seems like a great place to use STUFF

Comment: @SeanLange seems like a great suggestion.

Comment: @SeanLange it seems to be good, I checking it

Comment: HAHA agree @SeanLange, brilliant....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would be inclined to use `stuff()` for this purpose:

```
update product
    set title = stuff(title, 1, 2, 'za')
    where title like 'mn%';
```

Comment: Thank you , it works :), but sorry I must to choose one answer

Answer (score 2):

use right and + instead...
the % is not a wild card in the replace.

```
UPDATE       Product
SET          Title = 'za'+right(len(title)-2)
WHERE        (Title LIKE N'mn%')
```

Incase stuff isn't in your version of SQL server...

Answer (score 2):

Try using `STUFF` as Sean suggested

```
update Product
set Title = STUFF(Title,1,2,'za')
where title like 'mn%'
```

Comment: Thank you , it works :), but sorry I must to choose one answer

Answer (score 2):

```
create table #t (title varchar(16))
insert into #t (title) values ('abcdef'),('defghi')

UPDATE       #t
SET          title = stuff(Title , 1,2,'za')
WHERE        (Title LIKE N'ab%')

select * from #t
```

Comment: Thank you , it works :), but sorry I must to choose one answer